# What is wrong with this Locking code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, locking

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Test c = new Test();
            Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(c.Lock));
            oThread.Start();

            Thread oThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(c.AfterLock));
            oThread2.Start();

            Console.ReadLine();

    }



public class Test
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public void Lock()
    {
        lock (((IDictionary)dic).SyncRoot)
        {
            for (var i = 3; i < 200; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                dic.Add(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
    public void AfterLock()
    {            
        Console.WriteLine(dic["100"]);
    }
}
```

AfterLock throws exception: The given key was not present in the dictionary

dic was locked by first thread ? why afterlock does not wait for first threads lock ?

Comment: I think to help we will need 1. a short complete, *working*, example that demonstrates the problem; *and* 2. a precise description of "not working" (eg. exact type and message value of any exception).

Comment: Not including the code that actually fails was a bad idea.

Comment: What is `ThreadSafeDictionary`? Where is the lock that you're having trouble with? How do you expect us to help you with a problem when you don't show us the code that is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to lock around the access to the object both when reading the data as well as when writing to the data.  Synchronizing around *only* the writes is not safe.
2. Nothing prevents your `AfterLock` method from actually running after your `Lock` method.  It can just as easily run before it, or, since you're not properly synchronizing around the read, they can even run in parallel.  You need to add some synchronization mechanism to prevent that method from running after the write, if it's execution depends on the write having run first (as it clearly does here).

Answer (score 1):

You should lock on a dedicated object, not the one you're trying to use.

```
class Example
{
    private object cacheLock;

    public static void Load()
    {
        // . . .

        lock (cacheLock)
        {
            CacheTable = (ThreadSafeDictionary<String, 
                ThreadSafeDictionary<Object, Object>>)CacheTableTmp.Clone();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A `private readonly object cacheLock = new Object();` can be a good idea, unless you have a really good reason to change the cacheLock after the Example instance was already created.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the object that he's choosing to lock on.  There's no reason for him to create another object here.